# Counting Principal G-Bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

How many principal G-bundles, $P\stackrel{\pi}{\to} X$, are there if $X$ is a point and $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}_4$, or the symmetries of a triangle?

Comment: There is only one: $P = G$.

Comment: You can only have nontrivial G-bundles when the base has interesting topology, and a discrete set does not.

Comment: Yes, correct.  I was confused.